# dovecot (+sendmail) fails to get email into thunderbird

Tags: debian, sendmail, dovecot, thunderbird

I ain't able to get emails into my email application (thunderbird).

I use 143 Imap to connect which i have tested with telnet and was able to login. But if i select the inbox with telnet it returns "0 EXISTS"

like so:

```
telnet 192.168.1.13 143
Trying 192.168.1.13...
Connected to sub.domain.net.
Escape character is '^]'.
* OK [CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 LITERAL+ SASL-IR LOGIN-REFERRALS ID ENABLE IDLE STARTTLS AUTH=PLAIN AUTH=LOGIN] Dovecot ready.
oper1 login update.site1 1234
oper1 OK [CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 LITERAL+ SASL-IR LOGIN-REFERRALS ID ENABLE IDLE SORT SORT=DISPLAY THREAD=REFERENCES THREAD=REFS MULTIAPPEND     UNSELECT CHILDREN NAMESPACE UIDPLUS LIST-EXTENDED I18NLEVEL=1 CONDSTORE QRESYNC ESEARCH ESORT SEARCHRES WITHIN CONTEXT=SEARCH LIST-STATUS     SPECIAL-USE] Logged in
oper2 select INBOX
* FLAGS (\Answered \Flagged \Deleted \Seen \Draft)
* OK [PERMANENTFLAGS (\Answered \Flagged \Deleted \Seen \Draft \*)] Flags permitted.
* 0 EXISTS
* 0 RECENT
* OK [UIDVALIDITY 1513093097] UIDs valid
* OK [UIDNEXT 1] Predicted next UID
* OK [NOMODSEQ] No permanent modsequences
oper2 OK [READ-WRITE] Select completed.
```

My dovecot -n
[gist.pastebin](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/db5c7d81e18cff8180f6484c8dcb2a54)

Mail location set to: /var/mail/

Comment: Can you see mail in the mailbox on the server?
Are there any errors in `/var/log/maillog`?

Comment: Yes, I am using webmin to view email on the server and there are heaps of mails. Maillog only returns: dovecot: imap-login: Login: user=<update.site1>, method=PLAIN, rip=192.168.1.138, lip=192.168.1.13, mpid=29821, TLS, session=<9eUSfjlgmgDAqAGK>

Comment: Is it a virtual user or unix system user and if it's a virtual user do you have entries in `/etc/postfix/virtual`?

Comment: Could you include **all** log entries generated during email delivery to the mailbox? [sendmail & dovecot]

Comment: It's a unix system user with a home directory: /var/spool/mail 

I've added a mail.log here:

[link]https://gist.github.com/anonymous/91a0b378865997190512920114613ab6

Just in case did i send an email to that specific email address